# Finding path of Builtins and executables for commands in Linux

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell

I am trying to implement 'whereis' command in C.  But I was able to implement it partially. When I ever I try 'whereis' in Linux shell, lets say for e.g. whereis ls .. I get the following results

```
$ whereis ls
/bin/ls
/usr/share/man/man1p/ls.1p.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz
```

I am able to get the first path using the PATH env.variable. But I have no clue how to find the other two paths. Any pointers how to find those paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux (but not on all systems, e.g. Mac OS), `whereis` searches in `$MANPATH` (or some other default places) for matching files, which for ls are something like this:

```
$MANPATH/man(.+)/ls\.\1(\.gz)?
```

If you really need to know how `whereis` works, you can simply look at its source....

Answer (score 1):

`man whereis` (Ubuntu 11.04) mentions the following paths:

```
/{bin,sbin,etc}
/usr/{lib,bin,old,new,local,games,include,etc,src,man,sbin,X386,TeX,g++-include}
/usr/local/{X386,TeX,X11,include,lib,man,etc,bin,games,emacs}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option generally available is `which`. It will return the fully-qualified path and executable name for the executable. For example:

```
$ which ls
/usr/bin/ls
```

It may help you in your `whereis` endevour and is also useful for portability in scripts to set the executable where it may be located in different places on different distributions:

```
my_ls=$(which ls 2>/dev/null)
[ -x "$my_ls" ] || {
    echo "ls not found"
    exit 1
}
```